# Sentiment analysis on tweets not working due to KeyError

Tags: python, api, twitter, word2vec, sentiment-analysis

I've collected tweets from the Twitter API and I'm trying to get my sentiment analyzer to give each tweet a sentiment score. The problem is when I run a string through the sentiment analyzer function, I keep getting the following error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\SHEHZA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11920/972135746.py in <module>
----> 1 text_sentiment(texts)

C:\Users\SHEHZA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11920/923749346.py in text_sentiment(text)
      5 def text_sentiment(text):
      6     tokens = [token.casefold() for token in TOKEN_RE.findall(text)]
----> 7     sentiments = words_sentiment(tokens)
      8     return sentiments['sentiment'].mean()

C:\Users\SHEHZA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11920/1851376262.py in words_sentiment(words)
     11 
     12 def words_sentiment(words):
---> 13     vecs = embeddings.loc[words].dropna()
     14     log_odds = vector_sentiment(vecs)
     15     return pd.DataFrame({'sentiment': log_odds}, index=vecs.index)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    929 
    930             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
--> 931             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
    932 
    933     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1151                     raise ValueError("Cannot index with multidimensional key")
   1152 
-> 1153                 return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
   1154 
   1155             # nested tuple slicing

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_iterable(self, key, axis)
   1091 
   1092         # A collection of keys
-> 1093         keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)
   1094         return self.obj._reindex_with_indexers(
   1095             {axis: [keyarr, indexer]}, copy=True, allow_dups=True

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_listlike_indexer(self, key, axis)
   1312             keyarr, indexer, new_indexer = ax._reindex_non_unique(keyarr)
   1313 
-> 1314         self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
   1315 
   1316         if needs_i8_conversion(ax.dtype) or isinstance(

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_read_indexer(self, key, indexer, axis)
   1375 
   1376             not_found = list(ensure_index(key)[missing_mask.nonzero()[0]].unique())
-> 1377             raise KeyError(f"{not_found} not in index")
   1378 
   1379 

KeyError: "['fbexclusive', 'kabooooom', 'hotstar', 'avengercon', 'evaaaaa', 'spiderhead', 'humayon', 'jaunga', 'dewanda', 'kidzcoolit', 'dooooope', 'marvelstudios', 'tfatws', 'screensplit', 'kamalas', 'avengerscon', 'msmarvel', 'bwahahahaaaaaaa', 'bilall', 'muneeba', 'feiges', 'demagh', 'hojay', 'tropey', 'marvel_quartz', 'pothum', 'wandavision', 'waeights', 'khanand', 'meyet', 'istfg', 'loooving', 'everyonehe', 'vellanis', 'iiiiiiiiiiiit', 'bruhhhhh', 'sonngggg', 'antiblackmirror', 'attackedt', 'jqk0mkiutf', 'waitwhere', 'propsandpraise', 'allenolantern', 'alphonas', 'nikalne', 'karachiite', 'rooskaya', 'primetimer', 'lovexalted', 'asjkdjjjskd', 'aaaaahhhhhhhhh', 'imanvellani', 'spiderverse', 'shdksks', 'koreena', 'melouk', 'chwineka', 'terrogen', 'bruhhhh', 'referencesmaking', 'watchalong', 'patreon', 'dinocomics', 'incels', 'noobmaster69', 'reputative', 'takesthebus', 'langbonus', 'comicartfans', 'saowee', 'seriouslythats', '30ampst', 'conventioning', 'attentiok', 'cgied', 'lypci3vbpe', 'quantumania', 'fi58plksqu', '0gyvitbwkl', 'ormax', 'i42dlwizey', 'screenwritings', 'bruhhh', '_i', 'khamala', 'dceu', 'waaiiitttt', 'uszche', 'kamaala', 'zardu', 'hasselfrau', 'steinfields', 'pussyklaaat', 'dni3biintz', '02iwv1ep9n', 'vallani', 'charichters', 'easyespecially', 'xennnial', 'cheugy', 'acnh', 'chakare', 'pateee', 'dschinn', 'powerswhich', '3_', 'niqb', 'hfidha', 'anjalis', 'popbuzz', 'hayats', 'sasnak', '0x49b842a1808ad21ffb106b659991591087aaab73', 'whattay', 'klashdlkashd', 'mrida', 'imanif', 'watchhh', 'tryingthat', 'admitthe', 'capeshit', 'bosslogic', 'likewandavision', 'heiffa', 'offivialy', 'ironylove', 'lineput', 'maveth', 'pleasantwonder', 'mencionaron', 'avenergercon', 'cassielang', 'backsounds', 'wkwkw', 'karachis', 'disneyplus', 'straightsome', 'omgiloveheriloveher', 'astahfirullah', 'lumetri', 'chatacters', 'nerdsplaining', 'discored', 'on_screen', 'arquez', 'gtfover', 'hearteyes', 'superherodoing', 'verslings', 'standom', 'covid', 'supehero'] not in index"
```

These are words people are using in the tweets I collected that aren't in the pre-defined word embeddings dataframe, which is why the sentiment analyzer doesn't work. What should I do to be able to get the sentiment scores despite some words not being in the word embeddings?  For more details on how the code works and to see the full code go to [this link](https://blog.conceptnet.io/posts/2017/how-to-make-a-racist-ai-without-really-trying/).

Comment: Please always include the *complete* error traceback when you have an error.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed it now so the whole traceback can be viewed.

Answer (score 1):

The most-simple approach is just to skip words for which you don't have vectors, as if they weren't there. If they're rare enough to be missing from your model, they may not be that valuable for your task.

And even if in context they're very meaningful, without enough examples to train a model with their meanings, it's safer to ignore them. The remaining words may be plenty.

If they're common in your data, but not your pretrained embeddings, you may need a better set of embeddings – something trained on data closer-in-domain to your texts. If you have enough texts, you can make your own domain-specific model that's likely to be better than something off-the-shelf trained from a different corpus.

There'll often be some marginal set of less-frequent words that, under best word-vector training practices, don't receive vectors because there were insufficient usage examples. (The typical default of these models to ignore words under some `min_count` of occurrences – usually at least `min_count=5` – usually improves the overall model, and remaining vectors, compared to keeping all those rare/noisy/hard-to-learn words.) But, as per above, simply eliding those words from downstream processes may work fine.

Another approach could be to use a word-vector model, like Facebook's FastText, that can synthesize guess-vectors for out-of-vocabulary ("OOV") words, by using subword patterns learned earlier. This works best for words that are typos or alternate-forms of well-trained words, and while the synthesized vectors are often better than nothing, they may not be very impressive, individually. (And, many words' meaning can't be sussed-out from their fragments.)

Comment: Thank you. I'll take your advice into consideration and see what I can do.